# Unable to set class variable from Axios api call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-component, react-state

I am trying to set both inPlayScores and finalScores in the fetchScoresCall.

I can see that it's populating like it should within that call but once outside that call is still null for all data.

I'm guessing I'm missing something relatively simple since I'm newish to React development so any help or explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated here.

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { View, Text, Easing } from 'react-native'
import TextTicker from 'react-native-text-ticker'
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global'

export default class ScoreRunner extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        initialState = {
            leagues: ['NBA', 'NFL', 'NHL'],
            scores: null,
        };
        this.state = initialState;
        this.loopForFetch = this.loopForFetch.bind(this);
        this.fetchScoresCall = this.fetchScoresCall.bind(this);
        this.child = null;

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._asyncRequest = this.loopForFetch(this.state.leagues);
    }

    inPlayScores = {
        NBA: null,
        NFL: null,
        NHL: null,
    }
    finalScores = {
        NBA: null,
        NFL: null,
        NHL: null,
    }

    loopForFetch = (leagues = ['NBA', 'NFL', 'NHL']) => {
        endPoint = '';
        leagues.forEach( async league => {
            switch(league) {
                case 'NBA':
                    endPoint = "basketball";
                    this.fetchScoresCall(league, endPoint);
                    break;
                case 'NFL':
                    endPoint = "American_Football";
                    this.fetchScoresCall(league, endPoint);
                    break;
                case 'NHL':
                    endPoint = "Ice_Hockey";
                    this.fetchScoresCall(league, endPoint);
                    break;
            }
        });
        console.log('finalScores are null here? ');
        console.log(this.finalScores);
        const strStr = <>
                {console.log('finalScores are null here as well?')}
                {console.log(this.finalScores)}
            <Text style={{color: 'green'}}>
                {this.inPlayScores['NBA']}
                <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
                    {this.finalScores.NBA}
                </Text>
                {this.inPlayScores['NHL']}
                <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
                    {this.finalScores['NHL']}
                </Text>
                {this.inPlayScores['NFL']}
                <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
                    {this.finalScores['NFL']}
                </Text>
            </Text>
        </>

        this.setState({ scores: strStr}, function() {
                // do something with new state
            
            this.setState(this.state);
        });
        this.setState.scores = strStr;
    }

    fetchScoresCall = async (league = null, endPoint = null) => {
                console.log('do we have a this.state.finalscores?');
                console.log(this.finalScores);
        if (league && endPoint) {
            console.log('league: ' + league + ' : endpoint: ' + endPoint);
            await fetch("https://www.sportsscoredatabase.com/api/v2/json/" + this.state.apiKey + "/livescore.php?s=" + endPoint, {
            "method": "GET"
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                // console.log(response);
                inPlayStr = ' :::' + league + '::: In Play: ';
                finalStr = ' :::' + league + '::: Final Scores: ';
                response["events"].forEach(score => {
                    if (score["strLeague"] === league && score["intHomeScore"] && score["intAwayScore"]) {
                        if (!["NS", "POST", "CANC", "FT"].includes(score["strStatus"])) {
                            inPlayStr += "  H:" + score["strHomeTeam"] + "(" + score["intHomeScore"] + ")" + " vs. A:" + score["strAwayTeam"] + "(" + score["intAwayScore"] + ")  |"  
                        } else if (["FT", "AOT"].includes(score["strStatus"])) {
                            finalStr += "  H:" + score["strHomeTeam"] + "(" + score["intHomeScore"] + ")" + " vs. A:" + score["strAwayTeam"] + "(" + score["intAwayScore"] + ")  |"  
                        }
                    } 
                });

                if (inPlayStr === ' :::' + league + '::: In Play: ') {
                    inPlayStr = null;
                } else {
                    this.inPlayScores.NBA = inPlayStr;
                    // this.setState({inPlayScores: {"`${league}`": inPlayStr}}).bind(this);
                }
                if (finalStr === ' :::' + league + '::: Final Scores: ') {
                    finalStr = null;
                } else {
                    this.finalScores.NBA = finalStr;
                    // this.setState({finalScores: {"`${league}`": finalStr}}).bind(this);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('no endpoint or leagues specified!');
        }
                console.log('do we have a this.state.finalscores?');
                console.log(this.finalScores);
    }        


    render(){
        console.log(this.state.scores);
        if (this.state.scores === null) {
            // Render loading state ...
            return(
                    <View style={globalStyles.scorestream}>
                        <Text style={globalStyles.scoreheader}>Live Scores</Text>
                        <TextTicker style={globalStyles.scoreStreamText}
                        duration={25000}
                        scrollSpeed={10000}
                        easing={Easing.linear}
                        loop
                        animationType = 'scroll'
                        bounceSpeed={0}
                        >
                        ... Loading ...
                        </TextTicker>
                    </View>
            )
        } else {
            // Render real UI ...
            return(
                <View style={globalStyles.scorestream}>
                    <Text style={globalStyles.scoreheader}>Live Scores</Text>
                    <TextTicker style={globalStyles.scoreStreamText}
                    duration={100000}
                    scrollSpeed={10000}
                    easing={Easing.linear}
                    loop
                    animationType = 'scroll'
                    bounceSpeed={0}
                    >
                    {this.state.scores}
                    </TextTicker>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Output of console logs are as follows:

```
 LOG  finalScores are null here?
 LOG  {"NBA": null, "NFL": null, "NHL": null}
 LOG  finalScores are null here as well?
 LOG  {"NBA": null, "NFL": null, "NHL": null}
```

and

```
 LOG  do we have a this.state.finalscores?
 LOG  {"NBA": " :::NBA::: Final Scores:   H:Minnesota Timberwolves(116) vs. A:Phoenix Suns(125)  |  H:Oklahoma City Thunder(118) vs. A:Orlando Magic(102)  |  H:Dallas Mavericks(110) vs. A:Houston Rockets(91)  |  H:Los Angeles Lakers(121) vs. A:Philadelphia 76ers(126)  |  H:Portland Trail Blazers(96) vs. A:San Antonio Spurs(133)  |", "NFL": null, "NHL": null}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setState` to tell React to update the UI with this piece of a new state for you, **after** the asynchronous call (API call in this case) is done.

The `setState` at the end of `loopForFetch` method is actually being called **before** the API call is resolved. Hence, the class variables `inPlayScores` and `finalScores` at that moment in time are still not being updated. You could try to move these codes below to the request callback:

```
// ...
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    // your logic for updating class variables...
    const strStr = <>
        <Text style={{color: 'green'}}>
            {this.inPlayScores['NBA']}
            <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
                {this.finalScores.NBA}
            </Text>
            {this.inPlayScores['NHL']}
            <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
                {this.finalScores['NHL']}
            </Text>
            {this.inPlayScores['NFL']}
            <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
                {this.finalScores['NFL']}
            </Text>
        </Text>
    </>
    this.setState({ scores: strStr })
})
```

I'd still recommend using React state over class variables in this case since it's that kind of data where you want it to reflect on the UI. So that the UI could "react" to the state change.

Here's [a CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-variable-as-state-w2ey7x?file=/src/App.js) for comparing these two approaches. The class variable update won't reflect on the UI until you call `setState`. Whereas using the "React state" approach, things are a bit reactive/declarative because the state managing and UI rerendering are handled/triggered by `setState`.

This one is a bit off-topic. But I'd also recommend rendering `strStr` directly instead of keeping it in `this.state.scores`.